# How to avoid duplicates populating array with async service

Tags: javascript, angular, asynchronous, rxjs, rxjs5

I have a component that fetches content from a service to process it. The thing is I can have multiple calls to this function, which results in duplicates on my array. I the following workaround:

```ts
    getOptions(): Observable<PickQuality[]> {
    console.log("MY LENGTH: ", this.options.length) // <=== Always returns 0 because the callback hasn't run yet
    if(this.options.length == 0) {
        this.championService.getChampions()
            .subscribe(champions => {
                champions.forEach(champion => this.options.push(new PickQuality(champion, 0)));
                this.reevaluate();
                this.optionsSubject.next(this.options);
            });

        return this.optionsSubject.asObservable();
    }
    else
        return Observable.of(this.options);
}
```

and it didn't work, and then I tried the following trick inside the callback (where the `this.options.length` is correctly recognized):

```ts
                    if(this.options.length != 0) return; // <=== Looks bad!
```

which actually worked but seemed extremely inefficient to me, since the call to my service is still executed. How can I fix this?

Comment: Use a `Set`. That's what they're for. #math

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend to restructure your code a little:

```
if (this.options.length == 0) {
    let source = this.championService.getChampions()
        .share();

    source.subscribe(champions => {
        // ... whatever
        this.options = whateverResult;
    });

    return source;
} else {
    return Observable.of(this.options);
}
```

Now you can avoid using Subjects and return the source Observable which represents the HTTP request and is shared via the `share()` operator. This means there's only one HTTP request and its result is sent to this internal `subscribe()` call as well as to the subscriber outside this method.

Answer (score 0):

Check for duplicates before pushing them.

```ts
this.championService.getChampions()
.subscribe(champions => {
    champions.forEach(champion => {
       if (champions.indexOf(champion) == -1)
          this.options.push(new PickQuality(champion, 0));
    });
    this.reevaluate();
    this.optionsSubject.next(this.options);
});
```